# Добавить элемент если он отсутсвует на странице js

Tags: javascript

Есть слайдер, для работы работы которого необходим `slider.min.js` . Так как слайдер используется не на всех страницах, я не стала подключать его в шаблон сайта, а подключаю его непосредственно в коде шаблона этого слайдера.

Если на странице более одного слайдера, тогда `slider.min.js` подключается несколько раз, в зависимости от общего количества слайдеров.

Я хотела создать условие js при, котором `slider.min.js` подключается только один раз. То есть, если `.src = 'js/slider.min.js';` уже есть на странице, то не подключать.

Как добавить скрипт через js я разобралась, но как добавить условие для дублирующихся `.src = 'js/slider.min.js';` не знаю. Благодарю за помощь

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
      .appendChild(
        document.createElement('script')
      )
      .src = 'js/slider.min.js';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Если есть доступ к коду слайдера:

В случае если вы можете изменить скрипт слайдера, можно в нём добавить глобальную переменную и затем проверять её значение:
**В слайдере:**
`window.isSliderImpoted = true`
**В скрипте:**
`if(!window.isSliderImpoted) // подключаем   else // не подключаем`

### Если нет доступа к коду слайдера:

```
const slider = document.querySelector('[src="slider.min.js"]')
if (!slider) // Подключаем
else // Не подключаем
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Во втором случае "Если нет доступа к коду слайдера" необходимо добавить код в шаблон сайта, я верно поняла? Скрипт проверяет наличие slider.min.js , если он отсутсвует то подключает скрипт? Если слайдера нет на странице, то `slider.min.js` все равно будет подключаться?

Comment: Первое решение подразумевает добавление `if(!window.isSliderImpoted)` в начало кода скрипта `slider.min.js`. A ` window.isSliderImpoted = true` непосредственно в php шаблон скрипта <script> window.isSliderImpoted = true</script>. Верно?

Comment: Нет, перечитайте мой ответ. `window.isSliderImpoted = true` нужно добавить в слайдер, таким образом если он подключён, поле `isSliderImported` будет равняться true. Проверять это нужно там где вы подключаете слайдер.